# Windows Store Apps: is there a way to exchange messages between share charm source App and target App?

Tags: windows-store-apps, winjs

I am working on a windows store app which have a feature to let user share content in my app with another app using Windows Share charm.

My question is: In the source app(my app), is there a way to capture the messages from the a target app? Say user want to share an image using the Mail app, I want to know whether that email is sent successfully.

I know for the target app, The ShareOperation object has some functions to send messages back to Windows, like:

```
shareOperation.reportError(errorText);
shareOperation.reportDataRetrieved();
....
```

Is there a way to capture these messages within the source app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Share process is opaque between the two apps. Sharing is a process by which the source app makes its data available to whatever target app the user might invoke, if any. There is not at present any capability to pass information from the selected target back to the source. In short, the source app hands off the data and then forgets about it...that's just how it works in the current systems.

Comment: Thanks! To whom who has the same question, here is the question I posted on MSDN, with the same answer.[link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/2bedbc33-f83f-4e72-b8b8-60fc2dad0457/is-there-a-way-to-exchange-messages-between-share-charm-source-app-and-target-app?forum=winappswithhtml5)